# Degree of freedom of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I had the following question while learning a sub-chapter called, complex matrices:
1) How many degrees of freedom are there in a real symmetric matrix, real diagonal matrix and a real orthogonal matrix? (The first answer is the sum of the other two because $A = Q\Lambda Q^t$)
2) Show that 3 by 3 Hermitian matrices A and also Unitary U have 9 real degrees of freedom (Col of U can be multiplied by any $e^{i\theta}$.

My question is what is degree of freedom in this context? I tried to find the definition, but there's no such definition from the book rather what I get from online is the degree of freedom is "the number of values in the final calculation of a statistic that are free to vary". I hope someone can enlighten me about this question, especially the definition of degree of freedom.